# Walker_Nav_Menu creating too many closing tags?

Tags: menus, walker, post-type

created this walker below to create a set of tabs. All looks ok but in the source there are several more  than there should be causing validation errors.

I only want to generate a tab for 'question' post types.

code -

```
        $mmArgs  = array(
          'menu'            => 'competitionmenu', 
          'container'       => 'div', 
          'container_class' => 'summary_chart_tab_icons', 
          'menu_id' => 'summary_chart_tab_icons',
          'menu_class'      => 'summary_chart_tab_icons clearfix', 
          'echo'            => true,
          'walker' => new summary_walker_2013_TABS()
    );

    wp_nav_menu($mmArgs);

class summary_walker_2013_TABS extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args){

    global $wp_query, $current_user;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    $voted = hasVoted($item->object_id,$current_user->ID);
    $voteMade = $voted[0];

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
    $class_names =  ($voted ? ' voted' : '');
    $icon_state=  ($voted ? '-voted' : '');

    $class_names = ' class="tab-icon '.the_slug($item->object_id). esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' clearfix " ';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $icon_name = child_template_directory. '/images/images/tab-icon-'.the_slug($item->object_id).$icon_state;

    if($item->object=='question' ) : 

        $question = get_post($item->object_id);

        $output .= '<li data-default-icon="'.$icon_name.'.gif" data-active="'.$icon_name.'-active.gif" data-active-voted="'.$icon_name.'-active.gif" style="background-image: url('.$icon_name.'.gif)" id="tab_'.$question->post_name.'"  ' . $class_names .'>';

        $output .='</li>';

        $item_output .=  ''.$args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    endif;  

}
```

}

and extra closing li s are in twos before each

. I think it might be the menu items that aren't 'questions' coming through but how can i omit them in a walker?

best, Dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `$output .='</li>';` from your walker. The closing `</li>` is automatically entered by wordpress for every item. This is done in `end_el` function of the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class.

Comment: cheers. That helped but i can see now its adding </li> even for post_types that aren't 'questions'. Is there a way i can truly reduce using if($item->object=='question' ) : or similar somehow? Dc

Comment: In your class, create this other function `function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()){$output .= "</li>\n";}` & modify it as needed

Comment: ace thanks - starting to understand the walkers a bit better now! Final code function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()){  
  if($item->object=='question' ) : 
   $output .= "</li>\n";
  endif; 
 }